# Set the x-axis positions of violin plots

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to create violin plots for various levels of discretisation of data. The levels are non-linearly related to each other so I want to show that on the graph (e.g. level 2 is 1 step from level 1, but level 3 is two steps from level 2). I can do this with a boxplot using 'at', such that the boxes in the following code are spaced at the variable values:

```
toPlot = data.frame(value = rnorm(50), variable = rep(c(1,2,4,5,8), each=10))
boxplot(toPlot$value~toPlot$variable, 
        at = c(1,2,4,5,8), 
        ylim=c(min(toPlot$value)-1, max(toPlot$value)+1))
```

Is there an equivalent (or any way to do this) with a violin plot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [vioplot package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/vioplot/index.html) in exactly the same way, e.g.

```r
# install.packages("vioplot")
library(vioplot)
#> Loading required package: sm
#> Package 'sm', version 2.2-5.7: type help(sm) for summary information
#> Loading required package: zoo
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'zoo'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     as.Date, as.Date.numeric

toPlot = data.frame(value = rnorm(50), variable = rep(c(1,2,4,5,8), each=10))

boxplot(toPlot$value~toPlot$variable, 
        at = c(1,2,4,5,8), 
        ylim=c(min(toPlot$value)-1, max(toPlot$value)+1))
```

[image]

```r
vioplot(toPlot$value~toPlot$variable, 
        at = c(1,2,4,5,8), 
        ylim=c(min(toPlot$value)-1, max(toPlot$value)+1))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-07-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>